# How to assign data-toggle="dropdown" for parent link in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How can I add `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the parent link only for wordpress. That means identify whether or not the link has sub-link, and then add the `data-toggle` to it. I am able to add a class depends on depth, but the depth of a parent would be 0, which is the same as other links without sub-links. So a way to approach my question is to identify the parent link with something and unfortunately I am running out of coding skills to do that. I appreciate if y'all could help.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your parent has child or not like this

```
if ( $('#mylink').children().length > 0 ) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks, that could be be just what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that you cannot have an anchor inside of another anchor. Based on what your question, it sounds like that is what you are trying to do.

Reference: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links